# append table column based on amount of text

Tags: jquery, html, css

Rather new to this, but I'd like to put a bunch of text into a table cell and – if it's more text than what the max-height of the table allows – will automatically create a new column for the rest of the text to flow into.

**HTML**

```
<table id="text" style="max-height: 150px; width:300px;" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td id="sized">Phasellus velit nisl, interdum in tempor tempus, luctus quis purus. Curabitur dapibus purus quis dui tristique lacinia. Maecenas ut venenatis augue. Vestibulum nec pellentesque orci, nec efficitur massa. Aliquam at est ac mauris molestie luctus. Nullam ac blandit nulla. Donec fringilla eros odio. Vestibulum cursus gravida urna in gravida. Fusce iaculis purus et sem vestibulum, quis mollis nunc rhoncus. Phasellus cursus lectus at bibendum pretium. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
$('#text tr')
if (this.sized > 150) {
.append('<td> </td>')
};
```

Comment: If you split the extra text into an adjacent cell, that extra text will start at the top of the new cell...it sounds like a sloppy way to present text.

Comment: Think newspaper layout. It's more of a continuation of the text.

Comment: Gotcha, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55820190/2813224)

Answer (score 0):

Although there's no direct adverse effect on one's code, it's considered bad practice to use `<table>` for layout. A simple newspaper column layout can easily be done using the CSS property [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns). The following demo has the `em` equivalent for the lengths provided in question at browser default of `font-size: 16px` (18.75em = 300px / 9.375em = 150px).

The `columns` property is in shorthand form:

- first value -- [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) is the maximum number of columns allowed (demo allows up to 12).
- second value -- [`column-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts) is the ideal width of each column.
- [`column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap) is the width between columns.

```css
.text {
  columns: 12 18.75em;
  column-gap: 1em;
  max-height: 9.375em;
}
```

```html
<article class='text'>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
    dolor</p>
  <p>in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborumLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
    do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor</p>
  <p>in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
</article>
```